# Downloading files with bash via cron

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have build a bash script that gets .tar.gz files from IMDb and writes to a log file, the script works when run on its own as I can see the folder with the files present, but when I run the script via cron it doesn't work. Would this be due to permissions? I have edited the sudo crontab file, but I'm not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: Try calling with `/bin/bash yourscript.sh` ( full path ).

Comment: It is possibly permissions, or perhaps more likely environment. cron runs in a different environment to your normal shell. First thing is to find the error message. Cron sends any output or errors to the  mail of the user whose crontab is running the job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

`Cronjob` is a file that contains your job:

```
cat cronjob
* * * * * bash /path/to/script.sh >> /path/to/log.txt
```

Then you should set executable permission and start `cron` service:

```
chmod +x cronjob    
/etc/init.d/crond start  #redhat based servers like centos
/etc/init.d/cron  start  #debian based servers like ubuntu
```

After that you should tell `cron` service to run `cronjob` file:
    crontab cronjob

Your script should download a file.

If your script doesn't run you should run it from good path[full path], so your `cronjob` file would be something like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh >> /path/to/log.txt
```